# How to implement Multi-Threads in Common Lisp

Tags: multithreading, lisp, common-lisp

It seems there're already several thread implementations, as I noticed there're [Bordeaux Threads](http://www.cliki.net/Bordeaux-Threads), [Portable-Threads](http://www.cliki.net/Portable-Threads), and 《The Common Lisp Cook Book》 also gives a way to implement multi-threads, the package [mp](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/process.html) which I don't known how to involve it in my program, I can't find this package.

The problem is how can I choose a proper multi-threads library to meet my demand, as I'm also a C programmer, it's better like pthread, but it doesn't matter, I wonder which it's the most used multi-threads library, or what is the regular way for multi-threads programming in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to
[Quicklisp stats for November](http://blog.quicklisp.org/2011/12/project-download-stats-for-november.html)
bordeaux-threads is heavily used but I don't see portable-threads or
any other implementations. So I guess you could try it and see if it
meets your needs and look for another implementation if it doesn't.

I've barely used it but I've found it easy to use and the
[API documentation](http://trac.common-lisp.net/bordeaux-threads/wiki/ApiDocumentation)
is rather clear.

Comment: Thanks, I will try bordeaux-threads, its API documentation is really clear.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the de facto threading standard for Common Lisp is `Bordeaux Threads (bt)`, which is a portability layer over threading APIs of different implementations.

`mp` (which stands for multi-processing) is how threading API is called in LispWorks (and, if I'm not mistaken, Franz CL). You can use it directly (just like `sb-thread` in SBCL), if you are developing for some specific implementation, or you can rely on `bt`, if you aim for portability across all currently active implementations with threading support (CLISP doesn't have it at all).

Comment: I'm not sure whether there's a spell mistake you said about LispWords, I only heard about LispWorks, which is a commercial implementation, maybe I can't use it for development, as I can't afford the high price of LispWorks, I'd try Bordeaux Threads since so many people use it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, LispWorks is one of the commercial CL implementations. It also has a limited free version, which is called Personal Edition.